# XSLT If id has class

Tags: xslt

I simply can't find this anywhere. How can I write an if statement in xslt to show the words 'YES' if a div with an id of 'cat' also has a class assigned to it which is called 'true'?

Answer (score 1):

If the div in question is the current node, and you don't currently know whether it has an ID of 'cat' or a class attribute, then you might write

```
<xsl:if test=".[@id='cat' and contains(@class,'true')]">
  YES
</xsl:if>
```

If you're in a template that matches on `div[@id='cat']`, then you can use the simpler test `test="contains(@class,'true')"`.  (And conversely.)

Note that the test as just formulated will succeed for divs with `class="untrue"` -- if that's an issue for your situation, the solution becomes a bit messier.

In XSLT 1.0, the simplest way is to write something like this:

```
<xsl:if test=".[@id='cat' 
              and 
              contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' true ')]">
  YES
</xsl:if>
```

In XSLT 2.0, I'd write something like:

```
<xsl:if test=".[@id='cat' 
              and 
              tokenize(@class, '\s') = 'true')]">
  YES
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: "divs with class="untrue"" -- the messy solution is to add a space before and after the entire class string and check if it contains `&32;true&32;` -- i.e., with a space before and after. (Notation is `&32;` but you need an actual space here.)

Comment: True; I thought I had said that, but perhaps I didn't.

Comment: Homer nods. The construct `test=".[@id='cat']"` is not permitted in XPath 1.0, probably as an accidental bug in the grammar. It's not a big problem, because it can be written as `test="@id='cat'"`. I think some implementations allow the syntax even though the spec doesn't. It's allowed in 2.0.